# Google Calendar API: writer access error when setting up events on someone's calendar

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-calendar-api

```
HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/some-domain.com/events?sendNotifications=true&alt=json returned "You need to have writer access to this calendar.">
```

Hi. I'm getting this error when I try to set a calendar event from my service account via the calendar api. Can someone help figure what it means?

Is it due to some access issues on end user's calendars? Or is it due to some limitation on my own service account?

Please help.

Comment: Are you including the user's OAuth authorisation token that he got when authorising your service to write to his/her calendar?

Comment: I guess not as I have enabled domain-wide delegation. It was working fine for the past few years. 
https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account

i'm a novice when it comes to integrating these google apis.
Where should I put it anyway?

Comment: oh, this is inside a GSuite domain?

Comment: yes it is in GSuite domain.

Comment: Maybe you have to renew the credentials then? I assume you're passing credentials in to an authenticated request. Are you fetching the credentials each time or using some stored credentials?

Comment: I'm using the json keyfile which is automatically generated when you create your service account key. This file has all the necessary info for authentication.

Comment: you mean you're fetching the credentials each time using `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-account.json')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198646/discussion-between-saran3h-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It wasn't a code issue. Someone played around with a setting that controls who can access the client's calendar and create events in it.

[image]

Comment: Hello, where did you find this option on google calendar ? i don't get it

Comment: @ValentinGarreau found it: admin.google.com->Apps->Google Workspace->Calendar->External Sharing Options for Primary Calendars